# Unique values for constants

Tags: php

What would be a good way/best practice to assign values to constants used for enumeration (php 7) to be able to reliably tell the difference between the constant and the value?

In other words, given,

```
class x {
    const a=1;
    const b=2;

    public static function y($z) {
        return $z==self::a;
    }
}
```

how do I differentiate `x::y(x::a)` from just `x::y(1)` or `x::y(2)`?

I could use random values or strings, but that's not exactly *realiable*. I also thought about using static properties with something like `uniqueid()` (since I don't need the values to be consistent between requests) but that'd be ugly. I don't need to be able to do bitwise operations either.

Comment: Why do you need to tell the difference between `x::a` and `1`…?

Comment: Because there's a function where an argument can be one of the constants used as a setting, or an actual value to perform an operation. If the user wants to pass `1` as an argument, I don't know if he meant `1` as an integer, or the constant. I don't want to guess a value unlikely to be used. It's not that weird, it's like regular `enum`s in other languages.

Comment: Since you can only work with *values*, you will need to choose clearly distinguishable *values*. "Constant" isn't a kind of value. If the value the user may pass can be anything, not even restricted to just, say, numbers, then there's no real way to distinguish that.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was asking what would be the best practice to choose these values / or an alternative without using constants.

Comment: You might want to change the function signature to distinguish by different parameters then, if distinguishing by values is unreliable: `public static function y($user, $predefined = null)`, and call it like `x::y(null, x::a)`…

Comment: I agree that'd be the best way to go. I was thinking how to avoid changing the api. Thanks